# how to exit template prematurely?

Tags: xml, xslt

How do i exit a template prematurely?

Like I want:

```
<xsl:template match="asd">
    <xsl:if test="$true">EXIT TEMPLATE()</xsl:if>
    <!--my main code here-->
</xsl:template>
```

I'm doing it this way now (which is working of course) but unarguably the code above is much neater if there's a variant of it that works:

```
<xsl:template match="asd">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$true"></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!--my main code here-->
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. If your condition does not contain a variable/parameter reference (which are not allowed in match patterns in XSLT 1.0), then simply move it up into the match pattern, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="asd[not(<some_boolean_expression>)]">
    <!--my main code here-->
</xsl:template>
```

If `$true` is a variable/parameter reference, then conditionally apply templates:

```
<xsl:template match="parent_of_asd">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="asd[not($true)]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="asd">
    <!--my main code here-->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do exactly as you describe; XSLT is a declarative language, not a procedural one, it's not really designed with 'program flow' in mind. However, to paraphrase your example, you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="asd[not($true)]">
  <!--my main code here-->
</xsl:template>
```

The down side to this is that it prevents you entering the template in the first place, so you can't have anything before the 'if'.

NB: Strictly speaking the spec for XSLT1.0 isn't supposed to allow variables in a match condition like this, but many XSLT 1.0 engines will do it anyway, and this is only a problem if you're condition actually has a variable like this. XSLT 2.0 does officially allow it, however.

Comment: This has to be mentioned as XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: No it doesn't. I have to admit, I was kind of assuming `$true` was a representation of a more meaningful condition anyway, but you can define a variable or parameter in the root of the stylesheet and use it like this in XSLT1.0.

Comment: No you can't. XSLT 1.0 does not support variable references inside  template match patterns. If you were assuming $true not a variable, this must be mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps according to the spec for XSLT 1.0 it's supposed to be, but I've tried a few xsltprocessors and they all work just fine with it. Besides, that's only relevant if your condition actually has a variable; as I said I suspect that was an example.

Answer (score 2):

If:

- you are not using XSLT 2.0 (@Flynn's answer)
- you don't want get rid of your variable reference or use the `apply-templates` approach (@Iwburk's answer)

You can still use `xsl:if` and work with a negative logic approach:

```
<xsl:if test="not($true)">
 <!--your main code here-->
</xsl:if>
```